# What song is playing in "Lelouch of the Rebellion R2" episode 17 when Lelouch met Suzaku for the 3rd time?

Tags: music, code-geass

In episode 17 of *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R2*, there's a song playing when Lelouch and Suzaku met for the third time. ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78sqDgMhvK4&t=3m11s)).

What is that song?

Comment: i should warn people that the Video is geoblocked for at least Australia. getting *"Video unavailable. This video contains content from Funimation Entertainment, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds."*

Answer (score 0):

It's called Declaration of War, allegedly an unreleased OST. I found it on youtube by side while going through Code Geass tracks researching for another song, and I remembered it when I heard it in the video you linked to. It is somewhat similar to Naruto's Orochumaru theme.